# Javascript access json data inside loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have json data, now I'm trying to access it inside loop. But I got undefined.

Is there any way how to access it from loop?

```js
var list = {
  macAddress: 'C0:49:EF:D3:79:20',
  category: 'esd',
  dr1: 1,
  dr2: 1,
  dr3: 0,
  dr4: 0
}

console.log(list);

for(var i=1; i<=2; i++) {
  var pinName = "dr" + i;
  
  console.log(list.pinName);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List has no property `pinName`. You need the value of pinName to be evaluated as the key by calling `list[pinName]`.